# How to destroy monster nests?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've played for several hours now and already cleared 3-4 monster nests but I could not figure out how to destroy those. I got the bombs for so how to destroy the nests with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can destroy Monster Nests just like in Witcher 2. Crafting or Buying Bombs and using them on the Nests.

In the Witcher 3 it works the same way you have to blow up the nests but with some new twists. Before you would go to the nest and press a button to drop the bomb.

Now in the Witcher 3 you can throw a bomb towards the nest or use a destructive sign at it to destroy it.

> "look around the chamber until you spot the two smoking mounds lying
>   either side of the pit. As instructed, use either bombs or one of your
>   destructive spells to obliterate them" **- Quote from Guide**

The specific bomb to destroy nests in the Witcher 2 was the **Grapeshot Bomb**.

**EDIT**:

**Ghouls Nests** and **Nekker Nests** can only be destroyed with bombs. Get a **Samum Bomb** or **Grapeshot Bomb** (Most Common) and go to the Nest and will ask you to press a button to drop de bomb just like in **Witcher 2**. Some nests can be destroyed by using the bomb and **Igni** and some only with Igni.

**Endrega** nests (Eggs) can be destroyed using **Igni** and so can **rats** nests.

If you need to replenish your bombs just meditate with Strong Alcohol like Alcohest and they will refill along with your potions.

Comment: What type of monster nest is it? In TW2 you needed harpy traps to destroy harpy nests, for example.

Comment: so far I've encountered nests that I could destroy like I said in my answer. But I need to explore more to see if there are more varieties. Probably there are and as soon as I know I'll update with a full list of nests and specific ways of destroying them.

Comment: In witcher 3 you dont need specific bombs i think the item description just say "those bombs can destroy monster nests"

Comment: @Nitro.de I know but i added that statement just for knowledge sake xD

Comment: @Lokuzt ah good one xD i'll give it a try as soon as i'm home again. If i still cant find it i'll ask here again xD

Comment: pretty sure igni doesn't work, at least it didn't for me.  Has to be bombs, and there are three types of bombs that will work (I'm not playing now and don't remember what they are, but there is a popup on the first one you encounter)

Comment: "As instructed" part seems to be relevant. First area did not contain (at least for me, but I don't think it's random) any nest that was sign-destroyable, all of them needed a bomb. There might be some later in the game, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to mention you can loot nests after destroying them. I blew up several nests before I realized they were lootable once destroyed.

Comment: Ignore the part where he said did endraga nests can be destroyed by using igni. That is 100% false. It has to be bombs

Answer (score 3):

**Grapeshot & Samum bombs can both be used to destroy nests...**

You start with both of these recipes and can craft them yourself (you do not need a craftsman) once you find the materials. You can loot/harvest the materials in the starting area but saltpetre is not common however if you can buy it from a herbalist. Once you have crafted the bombs you can use them to destroy nests simply by pressing the action button/key when near a nest and Geralt will light and drop one in resulting in the nest exploding and you being rewarded with XP for destroying it a few seconds later.

Be sure to stick around for after the explosion as the monster nest usually drops valuable loot and crafting components.